# 3 dimensional scatterplot using radial axis in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, compass, scatter

I have data which I am plotting in Matlab that looks like the following:
[image]
This data is given as a list of xyz coordinates, and then I am just plotting it as a trisurf using delaunay.

However, I need to change the xy axis, so that it looks like that of a polar plot, like so:
[image]
whilst maintaining the z axis preferably with an axis title on the outwards radiating axis.

I need to maintain the look of the figure, just changing the axis format, but unfortunately I don't see any way to do this.

Thank you for any help that you can provide.

Comment: Have you tried using the matlab command `polar` or `polarplot`?

Comment: If I use polar or polarplot prior to plotting my data, like so: `t = 0:0.01: pi/2 ;
    polarplot(t, 10 * log10(cos(t))/(50) + 1)
    tri = delaunay(x,y);
    trisurf(tri,x,y,z)` It just gets overriden

Comment: You may need to convert your coordinates, which are cartesian, into polar coordinates, then plot it. `[theta,rho,z] = cart2pol(x,y,z)`

Comment: It's my understanding that trisurf does not support polar coordinates...

Comment: There are some files available on the matlab file exchange. Try looking into the [3D Polar Plot](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13200-3d-polar-plot)  file. It may be what you are looking for.